# Hibernate syntax error : Expected DOT

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I am getting the following error on the execution of the below hibernate transaction : `expecting DOT, found '=' near line 1, column 32 [update t_credential set status = :status , assigned_engine = :engine where id = :id]` .

Also, `t_credential` is a table and not an object. Does hibernate allow to use this way or does it compulsorily have to be an object?

```
for(Credential credential: accountList){

Query query = ssn.createQuery("update t_credential set status =:status , assigned_engine = :engine where id = :id");
query.setParameter("status", status);
query.setParameter("engine", assignedTo);
query.setParameter("id", String.valueOf(credential.getId()));
int result = query.executeUpate();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the HQL example here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-direct. It seems that you need to refer to an object: "update t_credential c", and then update it's fields, like this: "set c.status = :status" and so on.

Comment: Thanks that solves it though I guess t_credential has to be a mapped object and not a table.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Hibernate with SQL Query (and not HQL query), you may have to use a different function.

```
ssn.createSQLQuery(" ... ");
```

I never used this function, so I hope it's a good answer for you.

Max